# We have a silk embroidery Chinese painting and wondering if someone can decipher the stamp seal (Characters identified: 周爭煇印)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

We have a silk embroidery Chinese painting:

[image]

and are wondering if someone can decipher the stamp seal.